# How to make highchart correctly in Yii2?

Tags: php, sql, yii, yii2

I want to make chart in Yii2, but I don't know how to make the chart correctly.
This is my table

**TableGender**:

[image]

Here's the chart that I made in `Microsoft Excel`

[image]

I have made chart in Yii2 like this:

**HighchartController**

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Jeniskelaminreal;
use yii\helpers\Json;

class HighchartsController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {

        $masuk= Jeniskelaminreal::find();
        $awal = $masuk->orderBy('TahunMasuk ASC')->one()->TahunMasuk;
        $akhir = $masuk->orderBy('TahunMasuk DESC')->one()->TahunMasuk;
        // $data = $masuk->all();
        $arr_l = [];
        $arr_p = [];
        $tahun = [];


        for($i=$awal;$i<=$akhir;$i++){

                if($awal == $i){
                    $jum_l = count($masuk->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal,'JenisKelamin'=>'Perempuan'])->all());
                    $jum_p = count($masuk->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal,'JenisKelamin'=>'Laki-laki'])->all());

                }elseif($i > $awal && $i <= $akhir){
                    $jum_l = count($masuk->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$i,'JenisKelamin'=>'Perempuan'])->all());
                    $jum_p = count($masuk->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$i,'JenisKelamin'=>'Laki-laki'])->all());
                }
                array_push($arr_l,$jum_l);
                array_push($arr_p,$jum_p);
                array_push($tahun,$i);
                }               


        $data['tahun'] = json_encode($tahun);
        $data['data_p'] = json_encode($arr_p);
        $data['data_l'] = json_encode($arr_l);



        return $this->render('index',$data);
    }

    /*public function actionData()
    {
        return $this->render('data');
    }*/
}
```

and Here is the view **index.php**

```
<?php
use app\assets\HighchartsAsset;

HighchartsAsset::register($this);
$this->title = 'Highcharts Test';
?>


<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div id="my-chart" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>



<?php $this->registerJs("
$(function () {
    $('#my-chart').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Jenis Kelamin',
            x: -20 //center
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: $tahun
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Jumlah'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Laki-laki',
            data: $data_l
        }, {
            name: 'Perempuan',
            data: $data_p
        }]
    });
});
")?>
</div>
</div>
```

Those codes are to query some tables from database. But all I need right now is to display my **TableGender** to be highchart in Yii2. What may I do to display it in `Yii2`? Thank you in advance

Comment: Use [this module](https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts)

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts is javascript library, so to pass parameter to it from php  **array** variable, you need to encode it to json format. You could use php function [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), or yii2 built in function [Json::encode](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basejson.html#encode()-detail). So, i beleive your code should look like this :

```
use yii\helpers\Json;

...

<?php $this->registerJs("
$(function () {
    $('#my-chart').highcharts({
        ...
        xAxis: {
            categories:" . Json::encode($tahun) . "
        },
        ...
        series: [{
            name: 'Laki-laki',
            data:" . Json::encode($data_l) . "
        }, {
            name: 'Perempuan',
            data:" . Json::encode($data_p) . "
        }]
    });
});
")?>
```

Hope it's help.

Happy coding. :)